# Error while installing Vim in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and I get this error when I try to install Vim editor:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree  
      Reading state information... Done The following additional packages will be installed:   vim-runtime Suggested packages:   ctags
vim-doc vim-scripts vim-gnome-py2 | vim-gtk-py2 | vim-gtk3-py2   |
vim-athena-py2 | vim-nox-py2 The following NEW packages will be
installed:   vim vim-runtime 0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to
remove and 170 not upgraded. Need to get 6,199 kB of archives. After
this operation, 30.0 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you
want to continue? [Y/n] Y Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
xenial-updates/main amd64 vim-runtime all 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 [5,164
kB] Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main
amd64 vim amd64 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2 [1,036 kB] Fetched 6,199 kB in
1min 32s (67.2 kB/s)                                        Selecting
previously unselected package vim-runtime. dpkg: unrecoverable fatal
error, aborting:  files list file for package 'libpcre3:amd64' is
missing final newline E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
code (2)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The script written in this discussion may be your help.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319791

Note: the actual error is only this line, so googling with this will help you.

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'libpcre3:amd64' is missing final newline
```